# Gradle commands/configs to process annotations

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation, annotation-processing

I have a Java project that uses annotation processors to generate source code that must then, subsequently, be added to the compile classpath and compiled/packaged.

This project is built by Gradle, and so I am wondering how to invoke these annotation processors under the hood so that:

1. First the annotations are processed and the required source code is generated under `src/main/java`; and then
2. When Gradle gets to the compilation phase, that source code already exists and can be compiled like all the other sources

When I run `gradle clean build` the code does not get generated, and other sources (which depend on the generated classes being there) fail compilation.

**I am trying to understand what needs to be done so that Gradle will run the necessary annotation processors and generate the source code.** The specific processors at hand are those required by the [Immutables](http://immutables.github.io) project (that is, my app uses Immutables to generate immutable objects), however I would think the answer to this question is general and project-agnostic.

---

#### Update

Something like this (?):

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.1.0' 
    apt "org.immutables:value:2.0.21"

    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'         

    provided "org.immutables:value:2.0.21:annotations"
    provided "org.immutables:builder:2.0.21"
    provided "org.immutables:gson:2.0.21:annotations"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one should help you: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt. 
Example from the following link:

> ```
> dependencies {
>    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.1.0' 
>    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0' 
> }
> ```

**EDIT**

It seems that the library You want to use is already have manual http://immutables.github.io/getstarted.html

**EDIT2**

compile directive gives your project access to annotations, but apt directive would start apt(annotated processing tool).So the full build.gradle would be:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourpackage"//FIXME
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1//FIXME
        versionName "test"//FIXME
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt "org.immutables:value:2.0.21" // for annotation processor
    provided "org.immutables:value:2.0.21:annotations" // annotation-only artifact
    provided "org.immutables:builder:2.0.21" // there are only annotations anyway
    provided "org.immutables:gson:2.0.21:annotations" // annotation-only artifact
}
apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikto Yakunin (+1) however `compile 'org.immutables:value:2.0.16'` is already one of my listed compile dependencies and this is still not working. Ideas?

Comment: @smeeb see second edit, also do not forget to add all the code for android-apt plugin

Comment: Thanks again @Viktor Yakunin (+1) - can you please check out my update and confirm that my `dependencies` closure looks like it should? Also, can you perhaps give a brief explanation for why this works? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb added full build.gradle listing